# KivyMD - MDRectangleFlatButton - button shadow animation too slow

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Please help me figure out how to accelerate the button shadow animation for a KivyMD MDRectangleFlatButton. As per the documentation there is no direct parameter i can change.

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='s2'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        pass
    

MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
Screen:
    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'menu'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]

                    Widget:
            
            Screen2:
                name: 's2'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Screen2"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]

                    Widget:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Profile'
                        halign: 'center'

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'App'
                        font_style: 'H1'                  
                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: 'Select 1'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                        on_release: 
                            screen_manager.current = 's2'
                            nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                    

                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: 'Main'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                        on_release: 
                            screen_manager.current = 'menu'
                            nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
```

I'm getting this animation lag:
[Button Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6jkn.png)

So as the steps of action:

- open the drawer;
- select one of the choices from the lower menu
- the drawer closes, but there are remaining button animation on screen.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried the same thing and din't find any lag. Are you sure you're memory is empty while running this task?

Comment: Shashank, don't really know how to do that ..

Comment: For clarification, the shadow thing remains for like half of the second till the animation is over. But it bugs me that the drawer is closed but that things continues to play (even for a half a second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

KV = """
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock


MDScreen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            
            MDScreen:
                name: 'menu'
                
                MDToolbar:
                    title: "Navigation Drawer"
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            
            Screen2:
                name: 's2'

                MDToolbar:
                    title: "Screen2"
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Profile'
                    halign: 'center'

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                adaptive_height: True
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                spacing: "12dp"
                
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'App'
                    font_style: 'H1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]  
                                   
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: 'Select 1'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_release: Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: app.set_screen(screen_manager, nav_drawer, "s2"), .3)
                

                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: 'Main'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_release: Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: app.set_screen(screen_manager, nav_drawer, "menu"), .3)
"""


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class Screen2(MDScreen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='s2'))


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def set_screen(self, manager, nav_drawer, name_screen):
        manager.current = name_screen
        nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")


MainApp().run()
```